# Not able to switch to HIGH RAM in google colab pro account. Please let me know how to switch to high RAM

Tags: google-colaboratory, ram

I have a google pro account and I saw that the RAM limits for a PRO account is 25 GB. Even when I switch to High-RAM option, I see that when the session is connected the RAM is only 12 GB. Not sure how to switch to get 25 GB RAM. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did you try GPU or TPU?